# Spanned columns collapsing on Android web-browser (when using auto-fit pages)

Tags: android, html, css, html-table

Update: I've logged a bug report with Google - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22447&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

---

Update: @benni_mac_b points out that the problem goes away if you disable auto-fit pages. This 'solution' works on 2.1 and 2.2 - turns out that the 2.3 phone I was testing on had disabled auto-fit to start with, and when enabled the table breaks again.

Guess I'm now looking for a way to tell Android not to auto-fit the table (and override the browser setting). Not liking my chances judging by my Google searches so far.

---

I've encountered an odd issue with the Android web-browser and spanned columns - for example, if I have this structure:

```
<table class="amhtable">
    <col width="16.72%" />
    <col width="16.62%" />
    <col width="16%" />
    <col width="16%" />
    <col width="34.67%" />

    <thead>
        <tr class="heading">
            <td>Modifying circumstance</td>
            <td>Common pathogens</td>
            <td>First choice</td>
            <td>Alternative</td>
            <td>Additional information</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr class="heading2">
        <td colspan="5" width="100%">SECTION TITLE</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="body">
        <td>column 1</td>
        <td>column 2</td>
        <td>column 3</td>
        <td>column 4</td>
        <td>column 5</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

The spanned row will reduce to fit the size of the screen, even if the table itself is still wider. This means that the heading2 row's background is missing across most of the table in some cases, making it look quite odd.

This is not happening on iPhone, or any desktop browser (Chrome, IE, FF, Safari) that we're aware of - just on Android (multiple devices and versions).

The CSS:

```
.amhtable {
        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000000;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        padding: 5px;
        font-weight: normal; 
        color: #000000;
}

.amhtable td {
        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:black;
        padding: 3px;
}

.amhtable th {
        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#777777;
        background-color:#0084D6;
}

.amhtable .heading {
        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000000;
        background-color:#567ac4;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, DejaVu Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, sans-serif; 
}

.amhtable .heading2 {
        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000000;
        background-color:#82a3e7;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, DejaVu Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, sans-serif; 
}
```

So far, I've tried the following:

- Removing the `<col>` elements
- Adding a sixth column and empty `<td>` elements into each row
- Removing the border-collapse style ( after reading [Webkit Browsers Rendering for Table Depending on colspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384132/webkit-browsers-rendering-problem-for-table-depending-on-colspan) )
- Setting the width of the spanned column to 100% (along with the changes above)
- Setting a fixed width on the table and setting the spanned column to 100%
- Replaced the % based widths of the columns with fixed pixel widths
- Set the position to be relative for the spanned cell (and then the row) and set left and right to 0.
- Set the position to be relative for the row with left as 0, and width as 1000px
- Wrapped the table in a 100% wide `<div>`

One thing that we noticed yesterday is that the table should have a 1px black border - but there is a gap on the 2.1/2.2 devices we're testing on where the row doesn't complete. It really does seem to be a rendering problem on these devices.

Comment: It looks fine on 2.3 Android. (on opera mobile and on internal browser too) Can you show me a screenshot?

Comment: I can definitely say we've tested on 2.1 and 2.2 - it seems to be only the internal browser. I'm not sure what version the third device we've tested with is running, but it might have been 2.3 - screenshot is proving difficult

Comment: yeah - not on 2.3... but since not everyone is running 2.3, this isn't really a solution.

Comment: im having the same problem, did you find a solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508889/android-autofit-mode-causing-issues-with-css-width-in-web-page

Comment: no, and my bug at android development has had zero response: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22447&q=browser%20table%20width&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if the following will help:

1. Wrap those body rows in a tbody element:
2. Remove the width="100%" from your header row. Colspan="5" should span the width of the table anyway, with the browser sizing accordingly. I wonder if the Google browser is interpreting that literally as the width of the current screen.
3. Add the following to the class for .amhtable:

   ```
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   ```

To see if it's a relative sizing bug.

Out of interest, does this happen if the heading row appears anywhere in the table? Or is it just the first time it occurs after thead?

```
<table class="amhtable">
    <col width="16.72%" />
    <col width="16.62%" />
    <col width="16%" />
    <col width="16%" />
    <col width="34.67%" />

    <thead>
        <tr class="heading">
            <td>Modifying circumstance</td>
            <td>Common pathogens</td>
            <td>First choice</td>
            <td>Alternative</td>
            <td>Additional information</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="heading2">
            <td colspan="5">SECTION TITLE</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="body">
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>

</table>
```

What happens if you try that?

Other things you might try are putting the actual heading text in an element like:

```
<tr class="heading2">
    <td colspan="5"><span style="100%">SECTION TITLE</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you strip out all of the CSS and just display the table, is it still broken? After doing that, if you move the colspanrow to be the second row in tbody (say create an empty row with 5 columns in) does that still break it?

Comment: I've stripped out all of the CSS except a background-color for table cells - the problem still occurs. Also, my example is just a simplified version of a common table layout in our content, and yes, it happens to all colspanned rows that are wider than the screen no matter where they are placed in the table.

Comment: Good grief! I wish I had the Android SDK to hand otherwise I'd run this up. Without trying things like embedding a DIV in the colspan column, or just floating all the elements in the table left, the only other thing I can think of is to fudge it, by using a table with the column headers, a div for the section title, then another table for the body contents (with the same column widths as the header rows table). Yuck, although I'd probably only serve that one up if the user-agent was the Android WebKit browser.

Comment: I just had a go for all that, too: but this auto-fit feature is being over-zealous no matter what I do.

Comment: There's a lot of webkit attributes like initial-scale, minimum-scale and maximum-scale. I wonder if you start setting those to 1.0 will it override the auto-fit functionality?

Comment: Similar topic: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/css_width_unrel.html no great resolution though. Sorry I couldn't be of more help, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a mistake but did you tried to put on your table :

```
table class="amhtable" **cellspacing="0"**
```

Comment: setting the cellspacing here didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Is the total width of the columns suppose to be 100.01%?

Try reducing first column to 16.71%?

Comment: not the problem - i noticed that the columns didn't quite add up to 100% exactly, and replaced all the widths with pixel placements instead - no change to the colspan problem on 2.1/2.2

Comment: Also - the column widths are set from a FrameMaker document, and is calculated into percentages through an XSL stylesheet - so there is sometimes a rounding error.

Comment: I managed to get it to display correctly by disabling "Auto-fit pages" under the settings menu in the browser

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but try this method http://jsfiddle.net/DhAYd/9/

Answer (score 1):

The (X)HTML document in your bug report is not Valid; at best it is incomplete.  A DOCTYPE declaration (HTML 4.01, XHTML 1.0) or a doctype (HTML5) is required.  In the current HTML5 Working Draft, the [`col` element does not have a `width` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-col-element) (the W3C Validator says it is obsolete; you should use CSS instead).  But this also cannot be Valid HTML or XHTML 1.0, as the [`title` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.1) is [missing](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/good-titles).

As a result of the missing DOCTYPE declaration, the layout engine is likely going into [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html), and you cannot expect interoperable behavior.

Also, percentages in (X)HTML are [not specified to support decimals](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#h-6.6), although it is not explicitly forbidden.  A HTML syntax validator would not catch this error as `%Length` is an alias for `CDATA` (any character data).

You should

1. Validate your document: [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)
2. Make it Valid.
3. See if using integer percentages or CSS helps.

Only if you are still seeing different behavior, you should file a bug.

Comment: Have followed your suggestions, and there is still no improvement.